# Can't generate a Reflow project from photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe

According to [this video](http://html.adobe.com/edge/reflow/photoshop-plug-in.html) importing a psd from **Photoshop CC** to **Reflow** is as simple as going to the menu ***File > Generate*** and clic ***Edge Reflow Project***.

But this menu item is not showing in my case.

I'm using a Mac OSX 10.8.5, the 30 days trial of creative cloud for the moment with both **Reflow** and **Photoshop CC** installed and up to date. I also have Photoshop CS6 installed on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of exporting Edge Reflow projects, if you are not able to see a menu option for:

- File
- Generate
- Edge Reflow Project

Please check that you have the folder:

> < install directory > /Adobe Photoshop CC/Plug-ins/Generator/reflow.generate

If you do not have this directory, uninstall and reinstall Edge Reflow.

The Edge Reflow installer should automatically install the plug-in for you.